# Error during insert binary data in Ultralite database iPhone

Tags: iphone

Hi I am writing a iphone application where I need to store binary data i.e.; image in the Ultralite database.
I am using following code for this purpose.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file_name" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
ul_binary *byteData = (ul_binary*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);

ULTable *table = connection->OpenTable("NAMES");
if(table->InsertBegin()){
    table->SetInt(1, (maxId+1));
    table->SetString(2, [name UTF8String]);
    table->SetBinary(3, byteData);
    table->Insert();
    table->Close();
    connection->Commit();
}
```

This code is giving error 'EXC_BAD_ERROR' on line::

```
table->SetBinary(3, byteData);
```

This code works fine if i comment this line.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `ul_binary` is this:

```
typedef struct ul_binary {
    /// The number of bytes in the value.
    ul_length       len;
    /// The actual data to be set (for insert) or that was fetched (for select).
    ul_byte     data[ MAX_UL_BINARY ];
} ul_binary, * p_ul_binary;
```

So it's a struct. By simply doing the `memcpy` as you do, you also overwrite the `len` field and everythings messed up. So here's how you should do it (as far as I can see):

```
ul_binary *byteData = (ul_binary *)malloc(sizeof(ul_binary));
memcpy(&byteData->data, [data bytes], len);
byteData->len = len;
```

You also need to check that `len <= MAX_UL_BINARY` before you try to allocate the memory. And don't forget to `free(byteData);`.